# Infopath 2013 do not recognise Visual Studio 2015 for write custom code

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, infopath, custom-code

I try to make some custom validations of form fields on InfoPath form written in VS 2015, but InfoPath 2013 required VS 2012.

Question is pretty like this one
[Does InfoPath 2013 support Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701675/does-infopath-2013-support-visual-studio-2013),
But now is VS 2015 and maybe is someone find out solution for this "Microsoft feature".

Also, I have installed required addions in VS. I can create an infopath project in VS and there I can write some code, but I have not find out how to connect that code with form which I have created in infopath..

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get InfoPath 2013 working with Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Unfortunately no :/

Comment: That's disappointing, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: VS2012 VSTA does support custom code in Infopath
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zxue/2015/01/02/fix-visual-studio-error-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint/